# maintain special pattern occurrences regex perl

Tags: regex, perl, digits

I am trying to use perl regexp to normalize search strings in a search log against a library database.
I need to remove all digit occurrences,  would be:

```
s/\d*//g
```

*except* when I have a birth date like 1964- or a lifetime like 1903-1970 or 1903-70.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lookaround assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

For example, the following pattern

```
/\b(?<!-)\d+(?!-)\b/
```

would match a number like `42` or `1970` but not match:

- 1964-
- 1903-1970
- 1903-70

For example, given an input:

```
42 foo 123 1964- 1903-1970 456 bar 1970
```

using the above regex to remove the intended strings:

```
$ echo 42 foo 123 1964- 1903-1970 456 bar 1970 | perl -pe 's/\b(?<!-)\d+(?!-)\b//g'
 foo  1964- 1903-1970  bar
```

Comment: Exceptions:  `-1979` or `1-2-3`.  The spec is also unclear on if numbers should be stripped from w/i words, so the fact that yours wouldn't strip the trailing numbers in `bob123` could be a bad or good thing.

Answer (score 1):

A complicated regex could solve this, for sure.  However, I believe the easiest solution is to take advantage of one of regular expressions most powerful tools, namely greedy matching, and break this into two steps.

```
s{([-\d]+)}{my $num = $1; $num =~ /^(?:\d+-\d*|-+)$/ ? $num : ''}eg;
```

The LHS pulls any number and/or dashes.  Then the RHS leaves them if they match the specific exception that you requested.

I like the two step solution because it's quicker to see what's happening, and also the regex is less fragile so it's easier to adjust it at a later time with less risk of introducing a bug.  All you'd have to do is add any additional exceptions you'd want to the RHS.

It is possible to duplicate the above using just the LHS by adding a lot of boundary conditions that mirror the effect of greedy matching.  The below demonstrates that:

```
s{
    (?<![-\d])     # Start Boundary Condition to Enforce Greedy Matching
    (?!
        (?:          # Old RHS: List of expressions we don't want to match
            \d+-\d*
        |
            -+
        )
        (?![-\d])   # End Boundary Condition to Enforce Greedy Matching
    )
    ([-\d]+)      # Old LHS: What we want to match
    (?![-\d])     # End Boundary Condition to Enforce Greedy Matching
}{}xg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to replace all the digits except the digits are in format of `1000-` or `1000-90`?

Try this one:

```
(?<!\d)(?<!-)\d+(?!-\d*)(?!\d)
```

Comment: Your regex could be simplified a little by using a character class for the beginning negative lookahead assertions: `(?<![\d-])`  However, you're regex will fail on cases such as `-1979` or `1-2-3`.